# How to order number in jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have some number :

```
0,0,0,5,1,2,8,10
```

I want to reorder the numbers .The numbers which are `1` and `2` should shift at the end of numbers. like this:

```
0,0,0,5,8,10,1,2
```

Is it possible?

Comment: [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: No. I exactly  want number  `1` and  `2` be at the end of my numbers. Not sorting them.

Comment: Please fully explain the logic required, and not just "I want 1 and 2 at the end".  What do 3 and 4 do, or 6 and 7?  Also post the code you already have so we can help fix it.

Comment: @bita It's still sorting them, you just need to provide your own function to create whatever sort logic is required. See 'compare function': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax

Comment: I've removed the jQuery tag and added the Javascript tag.  I've assumed Javascript because of the previous jQuery tag, but this is definitely not a jQuery question.  Do correct it if you want to do this in a language other than Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your issue.

1. Loop over your array
2. If it's a `1` or `2` append it to temporary array `ab`
3. If it's a different number than 1 or 2, append it to array `aa`
4. Return joined arrays

```js
function extractOneTwo(arr){
    let aa = []
    let ab = []
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if ([1,2].includes(arr[i])){
          ab.push(arr[i])
        }else{
            aa.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return([...aa, ...ab])
}  


console.log(extractOneTwo([0,0,0,5,1,2,8,10]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @RoryMcCrossan [has pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686778/how-to-order-number-in-jquery/55687602#comment98056951_55686778), the [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is a solution:

```js
const arr = [0,0,0,5,1,2,8,10];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if ([1,2].includes(a)) return 1;
  if ([1,2].includes(b)) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as stated by many of us.

```js
const numbers = [0, 0 ,0, 5, 1, 2, 8, 10];

/**
 * Moves {toMove} values at the end of {arr}.
 * @param {Array} arr
 * @param {Array} toMove
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function moveToEnd(arr, ...toMove) {
  return [].concat(arr).sort((a, b) => {
    if (toMove.includes(a)) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (toMove.includes(b)) {
      return -1;
    }
  });
}

console.log(moveToEnd(numbers, 1, 2)); // 0,0,0,5,8,10,  1,2
console.log(moveToEnd(numbers, 0, 8, 2)); // 5,1,10,  0,0,0,2,8
```